# doctrine error when do clear before persist

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-odm

I'm getting the following error

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
```

Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, array given

after running a 'clear' before a 'persist'.

This is the code.

```
    $user = $userRepository->findOneById($userId);
    $dm->clear();
    $dm->persist($user);
    $dm->flush();
```

I know that making a clear just after retrieving the object from the database could be strange. But my inherited code is what it does.

any idea about the problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use `->clear()` after `->flush()` 
Official documentation [link](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html)